# Groovy metaclass in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I added a behaviour for **Map of Lists** (a map where the `key` is one `Integer` but the `values` are `List`) in Grails. If the `key` doesnot exist, I will insert the `Integer` `key` and one `value`. But if the `key` exists, I want to concatenate `values` as a `List` /rather than replacing the existing `value`.

```
/**
* E.g.
*  [1: [123, 456, 789], [2: [987, 654, 321]]]
*/
LinkedHashMap.metaClass.multiPut << { key, value ->
    delegate[key] = delegate[key] ?: [];
    delegate[key] += value
}
```

My question is:
**Where shall I put this in Grails?** in `Bootstrap.groovy's init` or as `AST Transformation` (if so, how?)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go for a Groovy extension module. These are loaded right during the Grails init phase so can be used pretty much anytime over the app lifetime.

More on these extensions can be found here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.cz/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html

The module loading support has been added to Grails as per this Jira ticket: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/1307

On the other hand I don't see anything wrong with using bootstrap either.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your "new" method I can't stop thinking about the already existing one:

```
def map = [:].withDefault{ [] }
assert map[ 'key' ] == []
map[ 'key' ] << 'value'
assert map[ 'key' ] == [ 'value' ]
```

The thing is, that concatenation has nothing to do with the `Map`, which contract takes care only about adding or replacing of values.

Here the possible problem is the `null`-value. if you do `map.someKey += 'aaa'`, you get a NPE, if the key doesn't exist. To make sure, that the values never turn `null`, at least upon the 1st call. This is where `withDefault()` come in handy.

In my example above I initialized the map with default values of `[]`, meaning that if the key doesn't exist, the new key gets inserted with the value of `[]`.

You could swap the `[]` with a `''` or any other type which allows concatenation:

```
def map = [:].withDefault{ "" }
map.newKey += 'aaa'

def map = [:].withDefault{ 0 }
map.newKey += 10
```

Comment: But the `map` variable in your example is of type `groovy.lang.MapWithDefault` not `LinkedHashMap` as in the original question. Still I see the new method `multiPut ` as unsafe - the `+=` can behave differently for arrays, numbers and strings which may not be obvious at the first sight.

Comment: I simply wanted to point out, that there's no need to introduce new methods, if they already exist

Comment: @injecteer I have edited my question in case I didn't make myself clear. Can you please help now? Is there a behaviour in groovy that allows me to concatenate values to a map if the key exists?